# How to define frequency of a job in application by users?

Tags: cron, playframework, job-scheduling

I have an application that has to launch jobs repeatingly. But (yes, that would have been to easy without a but...) I would like users to define their backup frequency in application.

In **worst case**, they would have to choose between :

- weekly,
- daily,
- every 12 hours,
- every 6 hours,
- hourly

In **best case**, they should be able to use crontab expressions (see [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html) for example)

How to do this? Do I launch a job every minutes that check for last execution time, frequency and then launches another job if needed? Do I create a  sort of queue that will be executed by a masterjob?

Any clues, ideas, opinions, best pratices, experiences are welcome!

EDIT : Solved this problem using Akka scheduler. Ok, this is a technical solution not a design answer but still everything works great.

Each user defined repetition is an actor that send messages every period to a new actor to execute the actual job.

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion on google-groups about it. As far as I remember you must define a job which start every 6 hours and check which backups must be done. So you must remember when the last backup job was finished and make the control yourself. I'm unsure if Quartz can handle such a requirement.

I looked in the source-code (always a good source ;-)) and found a method every, where I think this should be do what you want. How ever I'm unsure if this is a clever design, because if you have 1000 user you will have then 1000 Jobs. I'm unsure if Play was build to handle such a large number of jobs.

[Update] For cron-expressions you should have a look into `JobPlugin.scheduleForCRON()`

Comment: Yeah, indeed, source-code has been a helper in many occasions, I'll dig into in once again to check those things. Didn't know about scheduleForCron! Thanks ;)

Comment: I have checkd scheduleForCron and it reads the annotations from a class file. Which is in my case not a solution.

Comment: I don't mean that you can use `JobPlugin.scheduleForCRON()` directly, but it should be possible to transfer the code to your application.

Answer (score 1):

There may be two ways to do this depending on your requirements/architecture:

If you can only use Play:

- The user creates the job and the frequency it will run (crontab, whatever).
- On saving the job, you calculate the first time it will have to be run. You then add an entry to a table JOBS with the execution time, job id, and any other information required. This is required as Play is stateless and information must be stored in the DB for later retrieval.
- You have a job that queries the table for entries whose execution date is less than now. Retrieves the first, runs it, removes it from the table and adds a new entry for next execution. You should keep some execution counter so if a task fails (which means the entry is not removed from DB) it won't block execution of the other tasks by the job trying again and again.
- The frequency of this job is set to run every second. That way while there is information in the table, you should execute the request around as often as they are required. As Play won't spawn a new job while the current one is working if you have enough tasks this one job will serve all. If not, it will be killed at some point and restored when required.

Of course, the crons of the users will not be too precise, as you have to account for you own cron delays plus execution delays on all the tasks in queue, which will be run sequentially. Not the best approach, unless you somehow disallow crons which run every second or more often than every minute (to be safe). Doing a check on execution time of the crons to kill them if they are over a certain amount of time would be a good idea.

If you can use more than Play:

The better alternative I believe is to use Quartz (see [this](http://www.selikoff.net/2009/11/04/java-cron-job-quartz/)) to create a future execution when the user creates the job, and reproram it once the execution is over.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this.

If you don't have a really huge load of jobs, I'd just persist them to a table using the required flexibility. Then check all of them every hour (or the lowest interval you support) and run those eligible. Simple.

Or, if you prefer to use cron syntax anyway, just write (export) jobs to a user crontab using a wrapper which calls back to your running app, or starts the job in a standalone process if that's possible.

Comment: That was indeed my idea, but that means I will have to create a cron library knd of.